# get the best features from matrix n X m

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I have a `X` matrix with `1000` features (columns) and `100` lines of float elements and `y` a vector target of two classes 0 and 1, the dimension of `y` is `(100,1)`. I want to compute the 10 best features in this matrix which discriminate the `2` classes. I tried to use the chi-square defined in `scikit-learn` but `X` is of float elements.

Can you help me and tell me a function that I can use.

Thank you.

Comment: You're trying to do two things: reduce 100 features to 10 (this is called [principal component analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis)) and then predict the class of each row. [This function](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) might help you with PCA, and [SVMs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html) or [logistic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) might help with classification.

Comment: Anubhav no, this is not what you want to do. Hocine wants to do feature selection, not dimensionality reduction. PCA is completely unsupervised, meaning it doesn't look at the classes at all.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by `X` is of float elements. Chi2 works for non-negative histogram data (i.e. l1 normalized). If you data doesn't satisfy this, you have to use another method.

There is a [whole module](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_selection.html) of feature selection algorithms in scikit-learn. Have you read the docs? The simplest one would be using SelectKBest.

Comment: In my experience, [L1 penalty selection](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/feature_selection.html#l1-based-feature-selection) is the most general way of doing feature selection in scikit-learn: I've found it to works for booleans, (logarithms of) frequencies and Gaussians.

Comment: Same here :) (which is apparently a comment to short for SO)

Answer (score 0):

Recursive Feature Elimination(RFE) has been really effective for me. This method assigns weights to all the features initially, and removes the feature with the least weight. This step is applied repeatedly till we achieve our desired number of features (in your case 10).

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html#recursive-feature-elimination

As far as I know, if you data is correlated, L1 penalty selection might not be the best idea. Correct me if I'm wrong.